# Empty web content while running JHipster application with Prod profile

Tags: jhipster

1. Built a sample application using JHipster.
2. Ran via IDE - App comes up with db initialized with data (via liquibase)
3. Build docker image - Dev profile and web page comes up
4. Build docker images - Prod profile and web page is empty (except the footer).

I used the following commands to build the prod profile image and bring up the app:

Build the image: ./gradlew bootRepackage -Pprod buildDocker

Run the container: docker-compose -f src/main/docker/app.yml up

Is there some other config that enables the web content to be served?

Comment: No error in browser's console?

Comment: No. It almost appears as if the the content didn't get packaged or something. I do see the footer thats all. How would you create the docker image using the prod profile and run using compose?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `gulp build --prod` before building your docker image.